# Override Woocommerce's default css

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

The image for one of my buttons on the cart page is not filling the entire button. When I try to remove the padding it doesn't work. The CSS below is affecting the button.

```
.woocommerce a.button, .woocommerce button.button, .woocommerce 
.woocommerce-message a.button, .woocommerce #respond input#submit.alt, 
.woocommerce a.button.alt, .woocommerce button.button.alt, .woocommerce 
input.button.alt, .woocommerce input.button, .woocommerce-cart table.cart 
td.actions .button, .woocommerce form.checkout_coupon .button, .woocommerce 
#respond input#submit {

border-radius: 2px;
padding: 10px 40px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 40px;
```

The CSS below is my own and is for the correct button, but it doesn't do anything. If I toggle off the padding rules above in the browser, my CSS does work. Any ideas?

```
a.button.vipps-express-checkout{
padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd just disable the default stylesheet (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/).

Comment: Won't disabling the default stylesheet lead to other problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `a.button.vipps-express-checkout` has *lower specificity* (something like weight or priority, see [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity)) than the default CSS's `.woocommerce a.button.alt`. Specifically, your specificity is **0-2-1** (2 classes + 1 selector) which is lower than the default's **0-3-1** (3 classes + 1 selector).

Try adding `!important` (see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception)) to override default css for that particular attribute:

```
a.button.vipps-express-checkout{
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

If you don't wish to use `!important`, you can try to increase your specificity weight from **0-2-1** to **0-4-1** (adding 2 more classes) like so:

```
.woocomerce a.button.vipps-express-checkout.alt {
     padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Omg that did it. I had tried important! with the exclamation mark in the wrong place. Iamverysmart :/

Comment: I think all of us has done that at some point :D .  Anyone I added an update in case you didn't want to use `!important`